# NLog does not write logs when installed from msi setup

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm stuck on this NLog for production installer.
I have a setup project to create .msi file, everything works fine except the NLog because it doesn't create logs inside /logs folder. Running the application from visual studio using debug or release mode, it just writes logs. I can't figure out the issue.

P.S. The config is embedded into the App.config. I noticed that it writes on other location by changing the `{basedir}/logs` with absolute path but not where the exe file is located.

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <variable name="appDataLogDir" value="${basedir}/logs" />
    <targets async="true">
      <target archiveEvery="Day" openFileFlushTimeout="2" maxArchiveFiles="30" name="logFile" type="File" fileName="${appDataLogDir}/log_${shortdate}.txt" layout="|-&gt; ${longdate:universalTime=true}|${level}|${message}${onexception:inner=|${exception:format=tostring}}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logFile" keepFileOpen="false" encoding="UTF-8" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Comment: Check the nlog config and see where the file to be written and see if the  user /process ( identity underwhich the app runs) has access to that nlog folder

Comment: I changed the the access of the folder, set it to Everyone but still nothing happens.

Comment: Can you include the `nlog.config` in the question ? Maybe consider writing log-files to ProgramData using [${specialfolder}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Special-Folder-Layout-Renderer). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by running the exe file as Administrator. The program on where the program run is Windows 8. I think by default my `setup.msi` when installed is not administrator or that the windows user is not administrator or maybe it's now administrator but not the original administrator.

To make it semi-permanent, you can change the exe property to Run as Administrator by right-clicking the exe then `Compatibility tab -> Change settings for all users -> check the Run this program as an administrator`. Or rather to run it as administrator temporarily, you can right-click then `Run as administrator`.

Comment: Sounds like the default shim applied by Windows Vista (and newer) to handle legacy applications, that are not behaving to standards. This shim creates a sandbox, so the application think it can write anywhere, but it is just writing to its isolated sandbox.